# How to avoid intercepting all touch events?

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

There is this https://github.com/03uk/RippleDrawable
beautiful implementation to create a Ripple Effect on non L devices.

As you can see it is a `Drawable` that implements `OnTouchListener`.

The problem is that the Drawable intercepts ALL touch events, and therefore **cannot be used in ListViews and similar**.

How to avoid it?

I think the problem is in here https://github.com/03uk/RippleDrawable/blob/master/app/src/main/java/dreamers/graphics/RippleDrawable.java

and specifically here:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    final int action = event.getAction();
    switch (action){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            onFingerDown(v, event.getX(), event.getY());
            v.onTouchEvent(event); // Fix for views, to handle clicks
            return true; // fix for scroll, when ACTION_UP & ACTION_CANCEL not come

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            onFingerMove(event.getX(), event.getY());
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            onFingerUp();
            break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: i'm sorry for my issue, and i will try to fix it as soon as possible, Thanks for using :)

Comment: Lisa Anne, i'm done with bug fixing and new version is rolled out :)